# Emphatic "do" with "used to"

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, morphology, used-to

> I did use to live in London.
> I did used to live in London.

Which one is correct?

According to the usage of emphatic *do* with past tense (eg "I **lived** in London/I did **live** in London"), *did* should change ‘used to’ to ‘use to,’ but I didn't find anything about it except in English Grammar Today by Cambridge.
However, Cambridge used *did* with ‘used to.’ Shouldn't emphatic *did* change ‘used to’ to ‘use to’?

> **used to**
> From [English Grammar Today](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/english-grammar-today/)
>
> Emphatic *did*
>
> We can use the emphatic auxiliary *did* with *used to*:
>
> > We never used to mix very much with the neighbours, but we **did used to** say hello to them in the street. (Don't use this form in written exams.)
>
> — [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/past/used-to)

Comment: @sumelic looks to me like Mako212's flag, rather than the negation one...

Comment: @marcellothearcane: Well, the titles refer to different issues, but the answers both cover this topic. It could be marked as a duplicate of both. "I use to" is clearly a misspelling, while there is no consensus (at least not on this site, apparently) about the "correct" way to spell "I did use(d) to" or "I didn't use(d) to".

Comment: Before asking this question, I had read your possible dubplicates.

Comment: My questions is different.

Comment: Can you edit your post to explain how your question is different? "Don't" is just the negative form of "do": I can't think of any syntactic difference between them that is relevant to this question.

Comment: Please just tell me which one is correct.

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn't put a 'did' in the past tense one - 'I used to...'